# How to make dynamic chart using Vue component with chart-js

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js, chartkick

I am making Bubble sort visualization algorithm and wanted to show to the process of shorting using line graph.

I have tried to implement the computed property but the browser hangs.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Bubble Sort</h1>
    <p>{{ bubbleSort()}}</p>
    <line-chart :data="bubbleSort()"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      a : [12, 0, 4, 546, 122, 84, 98, 64, 9, 1, 3223, 455, 23, 234, 213] 
    }
  },
  methods : {
    bubbleSort: function () {
      let swapped;
      do {
        swapped = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++){
          if(this.a[i] > this.a[i+1]){
            let temp = this.a[i];
            this.a[i] = this.a[i+1];
            this.a[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
          }
        }
      }while(swapped);
      return Object.assign({},this.a);
    }
}
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

I expect the chart to update while shorting is happening.

Comment: could you share the tried computed property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304869/2358409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a computed property is not the best way to implement a bubble sort visualization, for two reasons:

- The computed property is re-calculated every time `a` changes, and you are changing the value of `a` in the computed property itself; this is probably what causes the browser to hang.
- There is no noticeable delay between executing the computed property function and updating the view, so the user won't see any animation.

Since you are not using `a` directly in your template, and the computed property has only one dependency, `a`, get rid of the computed property, it's not needed.

Instead, create a function that completes a single pass of the bubble sort algorithm, and call that function in a `setInterval`, cancelling the loop when a pass is made with 0 swaps:

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      a : [12, 0, 4, 546, 122, 84, 98, 64, 9, 1, 3223, 455, 23, 234, 213],
      intervalId: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    bubbleSort() {
      let swapped = false;

      for (let i = 0; i < this.a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (this.a[i] > this.a[i+1]) {
          const temp = this.a[i];
          this.$set(this.a, i, this.a[i+1]);
          this.$set(this.a, i+1, temp);
          swapped = true;
        }
      }

      if (!swapped) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.bubbleSort();
    }, 2000);
  }
};
```

Notes:

- Vue's reactivity system won't notice changes to arrays when accessing them via index, so `$set` must be used instead. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats.
- A bar chart will look nicer in this case than a line chart.
- `a` is a very nondescript variable name, try to give it a more meaningful and unique name.
- Be more precise than "browser hangs" when describing a bug. Does the browser window just freeze (i.e. can't interact with the page)? How long does it take for that to happen? Are there errors in the console? Etc.
- You have a typo in your question: `swapp`. Don't be so lazy. If you don't give a shit about your question, no one will give a shit about answering it.

Comment: Using the mounted hook the line chart component didn't bind the data prop.The line chart expects data when crating the component and for some reason it only works with objects so I converted to array using `Object.assign({},this.a)` though the documentation says it accepts array as well  as Objects.

Comment: The mounted hook has nothing to do with the data binding. I tested the above code locally and it works fine, so I'm not sure what you're doing. Can you post an example of your code in JSFiddle, Codepen, Codesandbox, or another service?